# Kobold2d Multiple Project Workspace - Xcode Confuses Files

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone, kobold2d

I really love using Kobold2d - it makes many aspects of Cocos2d development simpler.

But a major annoyance I've found is that since all new projects are contained within the Kobold2d workspace, if I try to recycle a class name, ie use the same class name for different projects ("GameManager", "GameLayer", "MainMenu", etc), performing a cmd+click (frequently how I navigate my codebase) will take me to the original instance of the class in the workspace...  Not the current project.

I've many times found myself making code changes before realizing I was working on the other project's version of the file.

Is there any way to change this behavior?  So far I've just been deleting the orginal project from the workspace, cleaning, and reindexing all the files.

This doesn't seem like an efficient workflow though and I doubt it's the way Steffen Itterheim @gaminghorror intended..

Anyone have an idea how to make sure clicking on a class name first maps to a file in the current project?

Comment: That's one of the shortcomings I fixed in KoboldTouch. For Kobold2D I recommend to setup a different workspace per project. You can do that manually, and drag in both your project as well as the Kobold2D-Libraries project so that they're side-by-side.

Comment: Probably time to pony up my $15 per month :)